# Adding new fields with dynamic field name sets field names to the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that contains a field which I want to add to the page when I click the add button.

```
// the div that contains the field
<div class="dependent-row" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; margin: 10px 0;">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="firstName dependentfield">
    </div>
</div>
```

A new set of fields display each time you click the add button.

The problem I am having is it sets all the added fields with the same name.

```
var index = 0;

$("#add-dependent-btn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    index++;

    $(this).after($('.dependent-row').html());
    $('.firstName').attr('name', 'fields[dependents][new'+index+'][fields][firstName]');
});
```

I know I need to zero in on just the field I am adding at the time I clicked the add button but can not figure out how to do that.

If I click the add button twice, here is the rendered html:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="firstName dependentfield" name="fields[dependents][new2][fields][firstName]">

<input type="text" value="" class="firstName dependentfield" name="fields[dependents][new2][fields][firstName]">
```

Comment: That is because you set all elements with class of `.firstName` after you add it to DOM.

Comment: @choz I know that, I need some way of dynamically assigning the firstName field name attribute. I have other fields but I just used the firstName when posting my question.

Comment: Do you just want to duplicate the `input`or the entire `.dependent-row`? I

Comment: I want to duplicate everything within the dependent row and make sure it assigns a different name="" for each field.

Comment: Check my answer and inspect on the `input` for their names. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically how you do it.

```js
var rowObject = null;

function addRow(lineNumber) {
  if (rowObject != null) {
    var newRowObject = rowObject.clone();
    var label = "Label " + lineNumber;
    var inputName = 'fields[dependents][new' + lineNumber + '][fields][firstName]';

    var myLabel = newRowObject.find('label');
    myLabel.text(label);

    var myInput = newRowObject.find('input.firstName.dependentfield');
    myInput.val('');
    myInput.attr('name', inputName);

    $('div.dependent-row').append(newRowObject);
  }
}

$(function() {
  rowObject = $('div.dependent-row > div.row').clone();

  $('#add-dependent-btn').click(function() {
    var totalRow = $('div.dependent-row > div.row').length;
    addRow(totalRow + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-dependent-btn">
  Add row
</button>
<div class="dependent-row">
  <div class="row" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; margin: 10px 0;">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="firstName dependentfield">
  </div>
</div>
```