# Jquery Clone and Update All ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I want to clone a `div` using it's `id` with many elements inside it which also has their own `id` that I want to change after cloning.

Consider this HTML structure:

```
<div id='wrapper1'>
  <p id='test1'>Hello</p>
  <p id='my-awesome-id1'></p>
</div>
```

I found [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127093/5530965) but it only changes the `id` of the main element you cloned and not the children.

Is there a way I could do it so that I could update all of the `1` into `2` and so on?

Comment: I just answered almost similar question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36040947/1627271). See if it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it and create a clone like:

```
<div id="wrapper2">
  <p id="test2">Hello</p>
  <p id="my-awesome-id2"></p>
</div>
```

```js
$('div').clone().filter(function() {
  $(this).prop('id', $(this).prop('id').replace('1', '2')).children().filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('id', $(this).prop('id').replace('1', '2'))
  });
  return $(this)
}).appendTo('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper1'>
  <p id='test1'>Hello</p>
  <p id='my-awesome-id1'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Forget what I mentioned above. Let's say according to my example `test1` is defined as `<p id='test1' data-num='1'>Hello</p>`, how do I do the changing for both the `id` and the `data-num` attribute?

Comment: I also just noticed that if an element inside `wrapper1` has no `id` in the first place, your solution would add that attribute but with no value. Would this be an issue or is it safe to leave it like that?

Comment: To answer your first question you'd just check for a matching data attribute and do s similar replace on the data attribute instead of the ID, and as to your second question an empty attribute is fine, however you could also just add a check first before doing the replace.

Comment: Should I put the check inside the first or the second `filter`?

Comment: The second (inner) filter checks the children (`<p>`) elements, so that one.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix everything now. Thanks a lot! Your solution only works for direct children I believe. It doesn't work for grandchildren or descendants.

Comment: That's correct. `children()` only looks at children. For deeper down the hierarchy you could use `find('*')`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That helped quite a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function changeIdNumberOnElementAndChildren(element, newIdNumber) {
    var $element = $(element),
        $elementChildren = $element.children(),
        oldId = $element.attr("id"),
        newId = (oldId) ? oldId.replace(/\d+$/, newIdNumber) : null;

    if (newId) {
        $element.attr("id", newId);
    }

    if ($elementChildren.length > 0) { // recursively call function on children
        $elementChildren.each(function(i, child) {
            changeIdNumberOnElementAndChildren(child, newIdNumber);
        });
    }
}
```

Then simply call it on a clone to change the ids:

```
$(function() {
    var clone = $("#wrapper1").clone();
    // below changes the ids so that they end in 559 rather than 1
    // (i.e. "wrapper559", "test559" and "my-awesome-id559")
    changeIdNumberOnElementAndChildren(clone, 559);
});
```